# Paypal Sandbox SSL Handshake Error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, tls1.2

Curl request to Paypal sandbox fails with

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

This symptom is already the subject of many stackoverflow questions - and I have solved it on several sites already, but in this case I have yet to pull the answers together for a working solution.

The problem domain is the enforcement of TLSv1.2 - which is active in Paypal sandbox and due in live soon.

This error typically occurs when either

- TLSv1.2 is not available due to curl/openssl versions on the site trying to
  call Paypal, or
- it is not being used in the curl call to Paypal so must be forced in curl options

However, this can be checked with a curl call to tlstest.paypal.com and in this case calls return

> PayPal_Connection_OK

without and with

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

indicating that TLSv1.2 is not only available but used by default. Since this would not be expected from the curl/openssl versions reported by the site, I infer that security updates have been backported.

Inserting debug info has confirmed that the only differences between the two calls (other than url) are these option values

```
     "CURLOPT_POST":true,
     "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS":"USER=uuuuuu&PWD=pppppp&SIGNATURE=ssssss&VERSION=204&METHOD=GetBalance&RETURNALLCURRENCIES=1",
```

My inference is that the handshake issue lies in the encryption of the data and so I have been looking at setting CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST. One recommendation is

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

which in this case does nothing to change the handshake error.

I have also looked into setting specific ciphers but have not found any values that don't result in the error

> failed setting cipher list

I have tried getting a list of ciphers on the calling site, using openssl_get_cipher_methods() which gives

```
'AES-128-CBC','AES-128-CFB','AES-128-CFB1','AES-128-CFB8','AES-128-OFB','AES-192-CBC','AES-192-CFB','AES-192-CFB1','AES-192-CFB8','AES-192-OFB','AES-256-CBC','AES-256-CFB','AES-256-CFB1','AES-256-CFB8','AES-256-OFB','BF-CBC','BF-CFB','BF-OFB','CAST5-CBC','CAST5-CFB','CAST5-OFB'
```

but none of these match the openssl names I have found on https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html which I was going to use to map to curl names taken from https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/nss.c via the RFC names.

Where do I go from here?

[Edited to add:]

- OS Linux 2.6.26-2-amd64
- PHP 5.3.19-1~dotdeb.0 (Zend: 2.3.0) [I am told, without explanation, that this is the highest available]
- OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
- curl version 7.21.0

I have tried a further test against tlstest.paypal.com adding a body to the curl request by adding option values:

```
  "CURLOPT_POST":true,
  "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS":"A=B&C=D",
```

Surprisingly, it still returns a successful response.

So I have now compared the two servers using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and the cipher suites available are different, and so are the servers' preferred orders. On tlstest there are more secure ciphers available and they are preferred, while on sandbox the weak ciphers come first.

So I'm still thinking the solution might be to specify a cipher list, and have been through this latest ssltest info in the hope of finding which one works on tlstest.paypal.com. In light of this I have now tried various things (and learnt that the format of this option depends on how openssl was built) but I have tested all the TLSv1.2 cipher suites reported by the test with the results indicated:

```
//  $cipher = 'AES128-SHA'; //handshake error
//  $cipher = 'AES256-SHA'; //handshake error
//  $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'; //handshake error
//  $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'; //handshake error
//  $cipher = 'AES128-SHA256'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'AES256-SHA256'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'AES128-GCM-SHA256'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'AES256-GCM-SHA384'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384'; //failed setting cipher list
//  $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'; //failed setting cipher list
    $cipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'; //failed setting cipher list
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, $cipher);
```

from tlstest.paypal.com - which is kind of disappointing as I was expecting one of them to work and not to be available in the sandbox.

Comment: i've seen errors similar to this many times, and it's almost always the same (although i recall some occations where it was an unstable connection instead), an update to a newer ssl lib/curl lib fixes it. even tho the tls 1.2 features in your version is present, there's probably a bug in the implementation, which for some reason doesn't show when you're not adding a body to your request (as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is doing). the solution is to fix your ssl lib, it is bugged. update it to a less bugged version.

Comment: What OS are you using, and what are the versions of OpenSSL and cURL?

Answer (score 0):

So my customer's hosting support finally 'fessed up:

> Our GRID platform which currently host's the site does not include ciphers for TLS1.2.

So @hanshenrik is correct. I infer that when you're testing against tlstest.paypal.com it fails if the correct version of the TLS protocol is not available. However success does not indicate that all elements are present for a successful proper call to Paypal sandbox - and specifically that the cipher suites are not checked on tlstest, even if a body is added to the call and this option is specified:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

You have to specify individual ciphers to get tlstest to throw a handshake error.